# php: inserting and updating tables

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert a data from a form into two tables (purchase and stock), also if there's a same item i want it to insert into purchase table (to record a purchase) and updating into the stock table (instead of purchase table so it cam add the quantity of the item purchased and no duplicate item on stock table). the problem is i don't understand the code logic for such action.

form page code snippet:

```
<form name="purchaseform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="submitpurchaseadmin.php">
<table>
<tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>
        <select name="type">
        <option value="opt1">Option1</option>
        <option value="opt2">Option2</option>
        </select>
        </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y"); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

current submit code snippet:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db_name="proyek";
$tbl_name="purchase";

mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass")or die("Cannot connect to SQL."); 
mysql_select_db('$db_name');

$type=$_POST['type'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];
$date=$_POST['date'];

$query=("SELECT * FROM stock");
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($row==0)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT into stock (item, qty) VALUES ('$type', '$qty')");
    mysql_query("INSERT into purchase (type, qty, date) VALUES ('$type', '$qty', '$date')");
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT into purchase (type, qty, date) VALUES ('$type', '$qty', '$date')");
    mysql_query("UPDATE stock SET qty=qty+'$qty' WHERE item='$type'");
}
header("location:purchasehistory.php");
?>
```

EDIT

based on your feedback, i've changed bottom bit of my code like this:

```
$query=("SELECT * FROM stock where item='$type'");
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($row=0)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT into stock (item, qty) VALUES ('$type', '$qty')");
    mysql_query("INSERT into purchase (type, qty, date) VALUES ('$type', '$qty', '$date')");
}
if($type==$row[1]) //$row[1] is item column in table
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE stock SET qty=qty+'$qty' WHERE item='$type'");
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT into purchase (type, qty, date) VALUES ('$type', '$qty', '$date')");
    mysql_query("INSERT into stock (item, qty) VALUES ('$type', '$qty')");
}
header("location:purchasehistoryadmin.php");
```

still got a duplicate on stock when inserting same item

Comment: Please, add minimum security and use function `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: first insert data to purchase and get mysql_insert_id() (http://php.net/mysql_insert_id) from it. use that id to create entry in stock table. Next time check the purchase item is already in stock, then just update the quantity field.

Comment: i'm a little lost there, could you give me a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query selects all the rows irrespective whether the items are equal are not. You need to modify you query so that it will check for those rows where the items are equal to `$type`:

Change this:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock");
```

To:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE item = '$type'");
```

Comment: i see, so if there's a same item on the table it would update instead of inserting another row?

Comment: i have changed the query to select by type, and if($row[1]=$type) still got duplicate on stock table

Comment: use `==` symbol i.e `if($row[1]==$type)`

Comment: still duplicates when using == in one table. any suggestion?

Comment: yes, i've checked that i got 2 entry on stock table where on purchase table i only got 1 entry

Answer (score 0):

Your corrected block of code :-

**correction 1:-**

```
mysql_select_db('$db_name'); // here db_name treating as a string
```

Should be :-

```
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

**correction 2:-**

```
 $query=("SELECT * FROM stock");
 $result=mysql_query($query);
```

Should be:-

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM stock";
$result=mysql_query($query); // or you can directly write query here
```

Complete block of code :-

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "proyek";
$tbl_name = "purchase";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Cannot connect to SQL.");
mysql_select_db($db_name);

$type = (isset($_POST['type'])) ? $_POST['type'] : '';
$qty = (isset($_POST['qty'])) ? $_POST['qty'] : '';
$date = (isset($_POST['date'])) ? $_POST['date'] : '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM stock";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($row == 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT into stock (item, qty) VALUES ('$type', '$qty')");
    mysql_query("INSERT into purchase (type, qty, date) VALUES ('$type', '$qty', '$date')");
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT into purchase (type, qty, date) VALUES ('$type', '$qty', '$date')");
    mysql_query("UPDATE stock SET qty=qty+'$qty' WHERE item='$type'");
}
header("location:purchasehistory.php");
```

**Most Important :-** Please do not use [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) as it is deprecated in latest version

Comment: not to be rude but this isn't going to solve my problem is it?

Comment: @RendySetiadi: The first change is, as you mistakenly used single quotes.